# Responsive Web Design - What Is the Best or Right Way to Put Images and Divs On Top of Image?

Tags: html, css, web

I have a background image for the "portal" to a new website.  On top of the  image, there need to be 5 images, placed in a unique pattern, plus 3 divs with text with links.  Here is a picture of what it needs to look like:
Link to design of Portal
http://dansdemos.info/clips/screenshots/portal.png

The portal needs to be implemented in a responsive design.

I have experimented with relative and absolute positioning, but I am having trouble figuring out whether either or both of those is the correct way to position these smaller items on top of the larger item.  So, I am struggling to figure out the best way of positioning the images and yellow divs on top of the picture.  My question is:  what is the best way of putting the images and divs on top of the background image for the portal?

Link to construction to live portal.
http://dansdemos.info/prelaunch/WorldClothingCorp_QA/

I think I can figure something out, but I really want to do this the "right way", or at least a good way.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I've had this situation myself before.

Resize the images you want to put on top to the same size as the parent (background) image. So place the images the way you want and make the rest transparent (png24, good transparency support and lower file size as gif).

Using your favorite image editing software:

1. Create a canvas of the same size as the background image
2. Place the background image in the canvas for reference (and lock the layer if possible)
3. Put in the overlay image and position like you want
4. Repeat this for the other overlays
5. Remove the background (reference) image and make the canvas transparent
6. Export the overlay images as PNG24

In the CSS use:

```
img { width: auto; max-width: 100%; }
```

…to make the images responsive. Now if the window resizes the images will respond to the width you specify to the page container.

More info on responsive or "fluid" images here: http://alistapart.com/article/fluid-images

Comment: A word of caution, `width: auto; max-width:100%;` will not upscale images if the container width can exceed the size of the image, which is usually why I prefer to use a simple `width: 100%;` instead.

Comment: True, just hammered on my keyboard what I usually use myself. Lol, "Hammered On My Keyboard" could actually be a title for the next hit song :P

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you position your background image within a relatively positioned div container.  Once you have that placed to your liking, You would do the same thing for the images to be placed on top of the big image except you will want to position them absolutely.

Comment: Hi  chawk, I had a feeling someone would tell me I needed to go backward before moving forward.  Better to get it right now though.  Why do I need to position the background image with relative positioning, instead of what I have?

I stripped everything off the page except the background image, but keeping a div structure I need, because I am using a responsive grid system setup with these divs.  Here is the link.. http://dansdemos.info/prototypes/htmlSamples/responsive/step07_responsiveGridBasics.html the background image is in the right spot, why does the positioning of this need to change?

Comment: I suppose it doesn't have to. I like to make sure I keep relatively positioned items in check, then absolutely position things within the relative item because the absolute items will never be affected by screen size, other div items, browsers etc... they will always retain their position within the parent div.

Comment: I thought you can position things absolutely using percentages to get them to respond to screen size.. I guess that is what I am about to try... maybe you already know that doesn't work.. :-)

Answer (score 0):

HTML:

```
<div id="container>
   <img src="..." alt="Background Image" /> /* Big Image */
   <a href="..."><img src="..." alt="Jacket" /></a>
   <a href="..."><img src="..." alt="Skirt" /></a>
   <a href="..."><img src="..." alt="Top" /></a>
   <a href="..."><img src="..." alt="Dress" /></a>
   <a href="..."><img src="..." alt="Jacket 2" /></a>

   <a href="..." class="yellowflag">RETAIL STORE</a>
   <a href="..." class="yellowflag">WHOLESALE USED CLOTHING</a>
   <a href="..." class="yellowflag">WIPING RAGS</a>
</div>
```

CSS:

```
#container {position:relative;}
#container > img { width: 100%; }
#container img+a         {position:absolute; top:30%; left:30%;}
#container img+a+a       {position:absolute; top:50%; right:30%;}
#container img+a+a+a     {position:absolute; top:30%; right:30%;}
#container img+a+a+a+a   {position:absolute; top:30%; left:30%;}
#container img+a+a+a+a+a {position:absolute; top:80%; left:40%;}

#container .yellowflag 
{
  /* Retail Store */
  background-image: url(...); 
  position:absolute;top:...;left:...
}
#container .yellowflag+.yellowflag
{
  /* Wholesale */
  top:...;left:...;
}
#container .yellowflag+.yellowflag+.yellowflag
{
  /* Wiping rags */
  top:...;left:...;
}
```

Comment: You can use more advanced CSS selectors if you don't mind dropping support for older versions of IE, but these are supported all the way down to IE 7 (Maybe even IE 6).

Answer (score 0):

As Chawk said you want to position your divs containing each image using position:absolute in a div containing the background image which uses position:relative. By setting them up this way, the 5 images will be positioned in relation to their parent element rather than the full screen.

Be aware that the divs around the images are currently displayed as blocks meaning they take up the full width of the parent element. You might want to set widths for them and display them as inline-block to make things easier.

Comment: Thank you Dolchio, for explaining more about why the div containing the background needs to be positioned using position:relative.  I understand what you are saying about the surrounding divs being blocks.  They are that way as part of a responsive grid I am using.  Here is a link to a stripped down version http://dansdemos.info/prototypes/htmlSamples/responsive/step07_responsiveGridBasics.html  It sounds like what you and Chawk are saying is that I should not use that particular grid system for the portal part of the website, or something like that?

Comment: FYI, the responsive grid comes from here http://dansdemos.info/prototypes/htmlSamples/responsive/step07_megaGrid.html I got it from Graham Miller via Google.